# How to move a file from local win 10 OS to a virtual machine on VMware ESXi?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I'm confused about this problem for a long time.
I have a VMware ESXi which has the management IP 172.31.49.30, there're 4  windows 10 OS virtual machines on it. 
[image: vmware EsXi]

**I can access the ESXi with IE Explorer from my local win 10 machine. How can I copy and paste a file from my local machine to the virtual machine on ESXi? Any simple method? Thanks.**

My current solution is a little complex. I save the file as Disc Image File (.iso) on my local PC, access the ESXi with IE, then upload the file to the ESXi. Enter the Win 10 VM and then select the disc image.
[image: Upload image file to stroage]

[image: Select disk image]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it currently. That ISO is mounted as a standard CD/DVD on the local VM's OS.

Alternatively, you could find out what the local VM's IP address is and connect to the hard drive via SMB from your local physical system. Example: Windows would connect to `\\x.x.x.x\c$` or Linux/Mac `smb://x.x.x.x/c$`

Comment: Thanks. But the IP of VMs and my local PC is not in the same LAN. In this case, can SMB work?

Answer (score 0):

add second Ip in your host windows 10 in the same range of your vms, and you should see it by smb like Kyle Ruddy said